# Fetching random set of values from a huge table

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing about 1 billion records. It has the following structure:

```
id | name | first_id | second_id
```

I also have an array with a set of specific words:

```
$arr = ['camel', 'toe', 'glasses', 'book'];
```

I now have to fetch all records from this table where:

```
- name contains one or more keywords from this array
- first_id matches 8
- second_id matches 55
```

Those values are made up of course, they change dynamically in my application.

**How can I do this so that it's most efficient?**

I tried the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE (t.name LIKE '%camel%' OR t.name LIKE '%toe%' OR t.name LIKE '%glasses%' OR t.name LIKE '%book%') AND t.first_id = 8 AND t.second_id = 55;
```

But it executes about 3.5s.

I just need to get about 3-4 random records from this query, so I also tried limiting results to 300. But it still gave me 700ms, which is way too long.

I also tried randomizing limit and offset, but I'd have to count all results earlier, so it would be even slower.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: camel toe, fnaar, fnaar

Answer (score 1):

First, learn how to use EXPLAIN SELECT. This should tell you a bit about how mysql will pick a strategy for your query.

If *just* using the `first_id` and `second_id` reduces the table to a small amount of records, it should be pretty fast, but it does mean that you need an index. Only 1 index can be used, so how you build that index depends on the cardinality of both `first_id` and `second_id`. If both only contain a limited about of values (say: under a hundred), you should make an index that references both.

But if there's still a ton of records in the table even for those `first_id` and `second_id` values, it means you need an index on the `name` field instead.

A regular index will do nothing for you for that field. You need a `FULLTEXT` index.

Comment: *FULLTEXT* is what I thought of suggesting since *1B records*

Comment: @Rahul it basically depends on the cardinality of `first_id`, `second_id` and `name`. If you can get away with an index on the `INTEGER` records instead, then that's preferable.

Comment: Yes true but his basic requirement is searching for keywords in 1B records which never going to help with `LIKE` operator but a `FULLTEXT` may speed up though.

Comment: Only 1 index can be used at a time. Which index is best depends on the nature of the data. If he's searching the entire table and he's _only_ doing the LIKE queries you are correct, but since he has more where clauses referencing other fields you might also be wrong.

Comment: In fact, adding the extra index could be damaging, because MySQL might pick the less efficient index to do the search. You as the dba are better equipped to make that determination =)